# Scala: Combine two methods, one returning a List, other a Set into one method using Generics

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Noob here. How can I create a single method that may be used in place of the following 2 methods?

```
 def makeListSavingsAccounts( numSavAccts: Int ): List[ SavingsAccount] = {
    var saList: List[ BankAccount ] = List.empty 
    for ( saIDX <- 1 to numSavAccts ) saList :+= new SavingsAccount( 5000 )
    saList
  } 



  def makeSetSavingsAccounts( numSavAccts: Int ): Set[ SavingsAccount] = {
    var saSet: Set[ BankAccount ] = Set.empty 
    for ( saIDX <- 1 to numSavAccts ) saSet += new SavingsAccount( 5000 )
    saSet
  }
```

Something like????

```
  def makeCollectionSavingsAccounts[T <: ???[ SavingsAccount ]] ( numSavAccts:Int ): T = {
    var saColl: T = ???.empty 

    for ( saIDX <- 1 to numSavAccts ) saColl  ?????? new SavingsAccount( 5000 )
    saColl
  }
```

We thank you  for sharing your vast Scala knowledge...

Comment: in order to keep things simple: why dont you call just the toSet method on the list in the 2nd method?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Guess I could also call toList on the first.
I just want to learn how one could use generics for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the way where Scala collection library is followed. So I believe following way is native.

```
scala> def makeSavingAccounts[T[_]](count:Int)(implicit cbf: scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[T[_], BankAccount, T[BankAccount]]) = {
        val builder = cbf()
        builder.sizeHint(count)
        for(i <- 1 to count) builder += SavingsAccount(5000)
        builder.result
      }

scala> makeSavingAccounts[List](3)
res0: List[BankAccount] = List(SavingsAccount(5000), SavingsAccount(5000), SavingsAccount(5000))

scala> makeSavingAccounts[Set](3)
res2: Set[BankAccount] = Set(SavingsAccount(5000))
```

Comment: You can change the type parameterization of CanBuildFrom to `CanBuildFrom[Nothing, BankAccount, T[BankAccount]]`. It will then be a able to find a CanBuildFrom instance even if you omit the type parameter when calling the `makeSavingAccounts` method.

Comment: I had to use 'new SavingsAccount(5000)'

Quite the signature! Looks like I have much to learn. Thanks one and all. Knut's suggestion also works. Guess I thought it would be simpler :(

Answer (score 3):

Without any magical stuff like can-build-from and builders:

```
def makeListSavingsAccounts(accsNum: Int ): List[ SavingsAccount] = {
    val accs = for (saIDX <- 1 to accsNum) yield new SavingsAccount( 5000)
    accs.toList
}

def makeSetSavingsAccounts(accsNum: Int): Set[SavingsAccount] = 
    makeListSavingsAccounts(accsNum).toSet
```

P.S. alternative implementation of `makeListSavingsAccounts` is `List.fill(accsNum)(new SavingsAccount( 5000))`